# Manipulating D3 axis labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with D3 for the first time and I'm trying to make a parallel coordinate graph. I basically am using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1341021) demo. The only real changes I've had is changing the data and changing the far right axis so it has strings instead of numbers as the labels. I do this by using the following:

```
        if(d === "Dog Breed") {
            y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
              .domain(dogData.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
              .rangePoints([h, 0]);  // quantitative color scale

        }
```

Unfortunately, if the dog's breed is too long, the text gets cut off, making it hard to read the label (one has to move the axis in its entirety to read it, but when they let go of it, it goes right back to where it was initially).

My other change were the following:

```
        var m = [30, 10, 10, 10],
        w = screen.width - 150, // Make it 150px less than the screen's width.
        h = 500 - m[0] - m[2];
```

The axis label code remains the same at:

```
          // Add an axis and title.
      g.append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); })
        .append("svg:text")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("y", -9)
          .text(String);
```

Is there any way to avoid the name-being-clipped-thing? Even shifting the graph itself over in its block about 20px would help, but I don't know where the code for that would be...

Comment: would be helful if u could make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @iJay my code reads in data from a file so I really can't? It is literally a copy of the example given in the link minus the few modifications I mentioned

Comment: To give yourself more room increase the left hand margin from 10 to say 150 in the following line:

    var m = [30, 10, 10, 150]

Comment: When you open up the inspector do you get <svg width="960" height="500"> and then <g transform="translate(150,30)">..</g>?

Comment: That remind's me that Kai Chang has developed a great plugin for [parallel coordinates](http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to manipulate var m to have more on the lefthand side in m[3].